# Will / Going to / Will be + ing

Tags: future-time, future-constructions, will-vs-going-to, future-continuous, future

Which sentence would you choose and why?

A) Go home. Your parents will worry.

B) Go home. Your parents are going to worry.

C) Go home. Your parents will be worrying.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends how late it is! If it's very late, the parents are probably already worrying (C) - if it's not yet so late, they will begin to worry soon (A or B).

Comment: I would say, "Go home. Your parents are worried." or "Your parents will be worried."

Answer (score 1):

> C) **Go home. Your parents will be worrying**

is the only one that works perfectly as it is.

A) **Go home. Your parents will worry**

is *less clear*. It sounds like, "Go home: your parents will worry,", i.e. "Go home and your parents will worry."

B) **Go home. Your parents are going to worry**

seems *incomplete*.

A and B would be clearer as either
Go home **or** your parents .....

or as
Go home. Your parents ..... **if you don't**.